# Performant filtering for a range from in memory data

Tags: java, performance, collections, filtering

I have a group of complex XML objects that is Store Location data and attributes

Some stores have 50 Store Locations, some stores have 1500 Store Locations and some have 20,000 Store Locations.

I want to create a list of Java Objects for a store that lets me filter store locations by Lat/long and other data about the store location

The most important filter is lat/long; in all cases I will need find all stores within an areas by a max and min lat and a max and min long example: between (40.146364,-75.406188) and (40.228694,-75.491295)

Duplicate lat/long values are allowed

I was thinking I'd create an object with a few key explicit properties I use to filter (like lat, long, store type code) and a string with the full XML

I was thinking that the objects go in a Collection like an ArrayList or another type and the key is a String of the Lat/long.

Filter the collection quickly is important; it will happen millions of times a day. Creating the Collection happens on startup and can be less performant if the filter is fast.

The lat/long filter has very high specificity; one example that has 1500 Store locations usually returns 50 or less store locations.

I was thinking I’d iterate over the Collection, and parse the key for the lat/long.  If the lat/long is within the desired range, I’d get the object and filter the other less specific search criteria.

Because of the number of queries and that the same query will almost never repeat, directly querying the database is not a good idea.  DB Caching will not happen because the parameters of each query will be different (the lat/longs often have 5 decimal places).  Chugging through the Collection means I shift the load from the DB to the App server but Oracle licenses and clustering is ALOT more expensive/complex than load balancing a bunch of AWS or Tomcat instances

Any ideas from the group on implementations for these requirements and constraints?

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you're talking about aren't scary and I would expect suitable performance from an in-memory implementation. If you can't store the complete object tree in memory, at least store the salient info (lat/long + ids) and filter on that.

As ever, I would implement some solution first before deciding performance is an issue.

Comment: I'm planning on doing what you described; what I'd like to know is does anyone have suggestions that will improve what and how I intend to store info and how I intend to filter the resultset to match the search criteria

Answer (score 0):

Because of the latitude-longitude query, you may want to store your data in an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).  [Here is a Java implementation I found](http://thekevindolan.com/2010/02/interval-tree/).  In a nutshell, an interval tree lets you query over an interval, quickly locating all objects with e.g. a latitude between x1 and x2; then intersect this with the objects that have longitudes between y1 and y2.

Comment: After looking at the implementationm I'm not sure this would be faster and it uses a TreeMap which is not good b/c it is allowed to have two locations with the same lat/long

Comment: You can swap the TreeMap for a [TreeMultiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html)